# Selecting the elements in a column that are in given time period

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to select the activities between 30min range for corresponding node and remove the activities if there are not in 30min range.

```
node <- c("ABC","ABC","ABCC","ABCC","ABCC","ABCC","ABCC","ABCC","ABCC","ABCC","ABCC","ABCC")

activity <-c("LOSS_OF_MULTIPLEX_SECTION-OMS_A","LOSS_OF_MULTIPLEX_SECTION-OMS_A","NODE_ISOLATION","NE_NOT_REACH_VIA_PRIMARY_MNG_INTERF","NODE_ISOLATION","LOSS_OF_MULTIPLEX_SECTION-OMS_A","NODE_ISOLATION","NE_NOT_REACH_VIA_PRIMARY_MNG_INTERF","NE_NOT_REACH_VIA_PRIMARY_MNG_INTERF", "UNDERLYING_RESOURCE_UNAVAILABLE-OMS_A","UNDERLYING_RESOURCE_UNAVAILABLE-OMS_A","UNDERLYING_RESOURCE_UNAVAILABLE-OMS_A") 

e <-c("2020-05-09 04:50:42","2020-05-09 06:16:54","2020-05-08 16:11:58","2020-05-08 16:11:58","2020-05-08 16:30:07","2020-05-09 03:00:08","2020-05-09 03:08:08","2020-05-09 03:28:08","2020-05-09 13:08:08","2020-05-09 13:10:08","2020-05-09 13:28:08","2020-05-09 14:28:08")

df <- data.frame(node, activity, e)
df
df <- data.frame(node, activity, e)
```

I have tried this code, but It's not correct

```
df %>% 
  arrange(node,activity,e)%>%
  group_by(node)%>%
  select(which(difftime(e)<=30)))
```

desired output

```
node <- c("ABCC","ABCC","ABCC","ABCC","ABCC","ABCC","ABCC","ABCC","ABCC")

activity <-c("NODE_ISOLATION","NE_NOT_REACH_VIA_PRIMARY_MNG_INTERF","NODE_ISOLATION","LOSS_OF_MULTIPLEX_SECTION-OMS_A","NODE_ISOLATION","NE_NOT_REACH_VIA_PRIMARY_MNG_INTERF","NE_NOT_REACH_VIA_PRIMARY_MNG_INTERF", "UNDERLYING_RESOURCE_UNAVAILABLE-OMS_A","UNDERLYING_RESOURCE_UNAVAILABLE-OMS_A") 

e <-c("2020-05-08 16:11:58","2020-05-08 16:11:58","2020-05-08 16:30:07","2020-05-09 03:00:08","2020-05-09 03:08:08","2020-05-09 03:28:08","2020-05-09 13:08:08","2020-05-09 13:10:08","2020-05-09 13:28:08")

df1 <- data.frame(node, activity, e)
df1
```

Comment: I can't understand the logic here. Can you please explain 1) why `df1`, the dataframe after filtering, has more rows than `df`, the original dataframe?, 2) what is column `e`? and 3) how to determine the duration of an activity?

Comment: I have corrected my fault. 2) e: time of the each activity occurs. 3).I wants to  select the all the actives that are in 30min range for corresponding node other wise remove those actives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
library(dplyr)

tlead <- . %>% lead(., order_by = ., default = max(.) + 1801) # 1801 secs
tlag <- . %>% lag(., order_by = ., default = min(.) - 1801)

df %>% 
  mutate(e = as.POSIXct(e, tz = "")) %>% 
  group_by(node) %>% 
  filter(e - tlag(e) <= as.difftime("00:30:00") | tlead(e) - e <= as.difftime("00:30:00"))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   node [1]
  node  activity                              e                  
  <chr> <chr>                                 <dttm>             
1 ABCC  NODE_ISOLATION                        2020-05-08 16:11:58
2 ABCC  NE_NOT_REACH_VIA_PRIMARY_MNG_INTERF   2020-05-08 16:11:58
3 ABCC  NODE_ISOLATION                        2020-05-08 16:30:07
4 ABCC  LOSS_OF_MULTIPLEX_SECTION-OMS_A       2020-05-09 03:00:08
5 ABCC  NODE_ISOLATION                        2020-05-09 03:08:08
6 ABCC  NE_NOT_REACH_VIA_PRIMARY_MNG_INTERF   2020-05-09 03:28:08
7 ABCC  NE_NOT_REACH_VIA_PRIMARY_MNG_INTERF   2020-05-09 13:08:08
8 ABCC  UNDERLYING_RESOURCE_UNAVAILABLE-OMS_A 2020-05-09 13:10:08
9 ABCC  UNDERLYING_RESOURCE_UNAVAILABLE-OMS_A 2020-05-09 13:28:08
```

Comment: `tlag`/`tlead` is a function that returns the previous/next activity time. For example, if activities A, B, and C occur at time 1,3 and 2, respectively, then `tlag` returns NA (i.e. no previous activity), 2, and 1.

Comment: For this question, we set the default value of `tlag` to the minimum time less 1801 secs because we assume that "no previous activity" (i.e. NA) means that the previous activity happens at least 30 mins and 1 sec ago. Then I guess that the "within 30 mins" in your question translates to "within 30 mins after the previous or before the next activity occurs". As such, we need e <= tlag(e) + 30mins or e >= tlead(e) - 30mins. @Isuru

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. As a extension is there any method to count the number of activities during selected 30min period.

Comment: @Isuru Something like this? `df %>% mutate(e = as.POSIXct(e, tz = "")) %>% group_by(node) %>% summarise(n = sum(between(e, as.POSIXct("2020-05-09 03:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2020-05-09 03:30:00"))))`

Comment: Yes may be work but how its modify for whole data set. because data set when large we difficult to find the time interval

Comment: I think this is beyond the scope of this question. Perhaps you should post it as a new question. @Isuru